# Javascript Regular Expression to parse URLs / Links into its Semantic Parts

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, url

For this set of example URLs / Links, provide all the semantic components of the URL / Link:

```
https://google.com:443 - https:// is the protocol, :443 is the port
cdn.ajax.com - cdn is the service, ajax.com is the domain, cdn.ajax.com is the FQDN
www.clients6.gc.google.com/project - clients6.gc is the subdomain, /project is the path
www.google.com/?query=x&#hash=y - ?query=x& is the query string and #hash=y is the hash string
```

I'm happy not to parse user/password (don't do it - poor security), or the query parameters (those are implementation-specific, ie some Java CGI toolkits used `;` instead of `&`).

Browsers crop off www and other service-type prefixes in the location bar, so it's now a de-facto standard that the service-type prefix is not part of the subdomain.  Unless you're a DNS admin.

Most browsers, phones, apps etc treat `www.` and other common web service subdomain prefixes like `https://www.` etc, so this should follow that de-facto standard.

So, to be clear, for all these forms:

```
www.sub.domain.google.com/path?query=x&#hash=y
https://www.sub.domain.google.com/path?query=x&#hash=y
https://www.sub.domain.google.com:443/path?query=x&#hash=y
```

a semantic Link parser should respond with:

```
{
  "protocol": "https://",
  "fqdn": "www.sub.domain.google.com",
  "service": "www",
  "subdomain": "sub.domain", /* no www. */
  "domain": "google.com",
  "port": "443", /* optional */
  "path": "/path",
  "query": "query=x&",
  "hash": "hash=y"
}
```

Comment: What is the context you're working in? Browsers have a URL class that deals with URL syntax.

Comment: @Pointy new URL('www.google.com:443/path?query#hash') provides pretty comical results.  But with some pre-processing I can see how this could be helpful.

Comment: Well sure, that's not a complete URL so it will be interpreted as a *relative* URL, which is correct. If you feed it a proper URL (beginning with "http://") you get what anybody would expect.

Comment: @Pointy I think I did justice to your suggestion.  If you feel otherwise, please make an answer out of it.

Comment: No you're correct; if you want to treat a leading "domain-like" thing as the start of a complete URL, that's fine; I mean, that's what browsers do. It is however ambiguous, because "./a.b.c/something" is a perfectly good relative URL. (even without the "./")

Comment: @Pointy Pedantically, I agree, so I'll rename `parseURL` to `parseLink`

Answer (score 0):

Using MDN [Groups and Backreferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Backreferences) docs and [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) online Regex authoring / testing tool, I found this solution using **Look-Forward, Non-Capturing, and Named Capturing Groups**:

```js
var URL = "https://guest:password@www.sub.domain.google.com:443/maps/place/Arc+De+Triomphe/@48.8737917,2.2928388,17z?query=1&foo#hash";

var parts = URL.match(/^(?<protocol>https?:\/\/)?(?:(?<credential>[^.]+)@)?(?=(?<fqdn>[^:/]+))(?:(?<service>www|ww\d?|cdn|mail|pop\d?|ns\d?|git)\.)?(?:(?<subdomain>[^:/]+)\.)*(?<domain>[^:/]+\.[a-z0-9]+)(?::(?<port>\d+))?(?<path>\/[^?]*)?(?:\?(?<query>[^#]*))?(?:#(?<hash>.*))?/i).groups

console.log(parts)
```

yields...

```
{
  "protocol": "https://",
  "credential": "guest:password",
  "fqdn": "www.sub.domain.google.com",
  "service": "www",
  "subdomain": "sub.domain",
  "domain": "google.com",
  "port": "443",
  "path": "/maps/place/Arc+De+Triomphe/@48.8737917,2.2928388,17z",
  "query": "query=1&foo",
  "hash": "hash"
}
```

Pointy pointed out that most browsers provide an URL class for parsing URLs into their components.

```
console.log(new URL('www.google.com:443/path?query#hash')
```

yields...

```
URL {origin: 'null', protocol: 'www.google.com:', username: '', password: '', host: '', …}
hash: "#hash"
host: ""
hostname: ""
href: "www.google.com:443/path?query#hash"
origin: "null"
password: ""
pathname: "443/path"
port: ""
protocol: "www.google.com:"
search: "?query"
searchParams: URLSearchParams {}
username: ""
[[Prototype]]: URL
```

It expects an URL, either absolute, or in context of window.location.href if you're in a browser, so a little pre-processing and a little post-processing...

```js
const link = 'www.sub.domain.google.com:443/path?query=1#hash';

function parseLink(link){
  link.match(/^[a-z]+:/) || (link = 'https://' + link);
  var u = new URL(link);
  var m = u.host.match(/^(?:(?<service>www|ww\d|cdn|mail|pop\d+|ns\d+|git)\.)?(?:(?<subdomain>[^:/]+)\.)*(?<domain>[^:/]+\.[a-z0-9]+)/).groups;
  return {
    fqdn:u.host,
    domain:m.domain,
    subdomain:m.subdomain,
    service:m.service,
    path:u.pathname,
    port:u.port,
    query:u.search,
    hash:u.hash,
    params:Object.fromEntries(u.searchParams.entries())
  }
}
console.log(parseLink(link))
```

yields...

```
{
  "fqdn": "www.sub.domain.google.com",
  "domain": "google.com",
  "subdomain": "sub.domain",
  "service": "www",
  "path": "/path",
  "port": "",
  "query": "?query=1",
  "hash": "#hash",
  "params": {
    "query": "1"
  }
}
```

Note that it collapses the (default) port value, and I threw in the query params parsing for fun.